# IE Iframe.contentDocument Access Denied Hosting on other domain

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, iframe, file-upload

In my application, I have an ajax uploader which falls back to iframe in browsers without native upload.

It works fine on my local machine. However, in dev on aws, it doesn't work. It throws an access denied error when trying to get the contentDocument. After reading a couple of articles and other questions, I have narrowed it down to the fact that, the document.domain does not match since the JavaScript library is hosted on s3.

I don't have the option to change the src of the iframe since the framework uses it in ways I can't determine.

In-lining the upload library did not work. Seems this is because the code is being called from from an external script.

What are my options? The src is [here](http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/assets.whisppa.com/js/upload.js).